# Delete a folder where argument list is too long

Tags: windows-vista

I have a directory which has a tree of directories inside. It's not the name of the dir that is long, it is the tree of dirs inside it that vista is complaining about.

I tried using-

```
rmdir /S [MyDirectory]
```

Didn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Rename dirs further up the path (to single characters if possible), thus reducing the overall length until Windows will accept it. It's worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 2):

user 8.3 format:
instead of rmdir reallylongdirectory /s try rmdir really~1 /s /q

Comment: Use "dir /x" to view these shorter names.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ZtreeWin](http://www.ztree.com/html/ztreewin.htm)